# sqlalchemy and airflow connection

Tags: python, linux, sqlalchemy, airflow

Using an UBUNTU 22.04

I recently updated my airflow to the newest version 2.7.1 and everything turns out fine. But there is one thing that went broken.

Many of my dags connect to an ORACLE database and execute scripts such as updates, inserts etc...

For that, I import the connection details from my airflow connection and use the function "create_engine" do create the connection and with that i execute whatever i want and that always worked very well.

But now i try to run a very simple dag:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.oracle.hooks.oracle import OracleHook
from airflow.models import Variable
# PARA AS TASKS
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# COLETANDO VARIÁVEIS AIRFLOW
folder_sql = Variable.get('folder_sql')
ora_conn_id = 'conn_oracle_dw'

# CONEXAO ORACLE
oracle_hook = OracleHook(oracle_conn_id=ora_conn_id)
conexao_orcl = create_engine(oracle_hook.get_uri())

###########################################
def test():
    conexao_engine = conexao_orcl

    inspector2 = inspect(conexao_engine)
    has_table2 = inspector2.has_table("TABLE_NAME", schema="SCHEMA_NAME")



with DAG(dag_id="test_dag",
         description="-",
         start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 21, 22, 45),
         schedule_interval="00 23 * * *",
         dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=90),
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:
    test = PythonOperator(
        task_id="extract_and_insert_MB51",
        python_callable=test
    )

    test
```

and it returns a very long error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py",
> line 192, in execute
> return_value = self.execute_callable()   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py",
> line 209, in execute_callable
> return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflowhome/dags/agendados/test_dag.py", line
> 36, in extract_and_insert_MB51
> inspector2 = inspect(engine_hanna2)   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/inspection.py",
> line 64, in inspect
> ret = reg(subject)   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py",
> line 182, in _engine_insp
> return Inspector._construct(Inspector._init_engine, bind)   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py",
> line 117, in _construct
> init(self, bind)   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py",
> line 128, in _init_engine
> engine.connect().close()   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 3194, in connect
> return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)   File
> "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 96, in **init**
> else engine.raw_connection()   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 3273, in raw_connection
> return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)   File
> "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 3240, in _wrap_pool_connect
> return fn()   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 310, in connect
> return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 868, in _checkout
> fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 476, in checkout
> rec = pool.*do_get()   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py",
> line 145, in *do_get
> with util.safe_reraise():   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
> line 70, in **exit**
> compat.raise*(   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
> line 207, in raise*
> raise exception   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py",
> line 143, in _do_get
> return self._create_connection()   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 256, in _create_connection
> return _ConnectionRecord(self)   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 371, in **init**
> self.__connect()   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 665, in **connect
> with util.safe_reraise():   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
> line 70, in **exit**
> compat.raise*(   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
> line 207, in raise*
> raise exception   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 661, in __connect
> self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)   File
> "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py",
> line 590, in connect
> return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "/home/bpo-intranet/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
> line 584, in connect
> return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams) TypeError: '**extra**' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

I tried to uninstall and install many packages thinking it could be a version error but nothing.
I also think it could be a airflow connection problem but this new version doesn't allow me to test the connection for some reason, it returns "testing connection is disabled in airflow configuration."

So if anyone can help me, i am desperate. Even with the testing problem, i would already be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

In connection, Delete Extra filed save and test

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).